How can I deploy october cms in a docker environment?
I downloaded october cms from repository, I want everything to work locally in Docker
i'm write docker compose file with Nginx, php-fpm and postgres containers. This docker config i'm use in other laravel projects, and it is work, but october cms doesn't work.
I get a variety of errors from 500 to 502
If I run the php artisan serve server, the project seems to work, but it feels like it's without js and css
version: '3.8'

services:

#PHP Service
app:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./docker/php/Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/html
        - ./docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    networks:
        postgres:

#Nginx Service
webserver:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/html
        - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
        - postgres

#PostgreSQL
postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:16
    hostname: postgres
    environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: postgres
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
        PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
        - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    networks:
        - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

#PGAdmin
pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
        PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
        PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
    volumes:
        - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    ports:
        - "${PGADMIN_PORT:-5050}:80"
    networks:
        - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
        - postgres

networks:
    postgres:

volumes:
    postgres:
    pgadmin:
    database_data:

Dockerfile php
FROM php:8.3-fpm

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libzip-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libwebp-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev libxpm-dev \
    libfreetype6 \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libgd-dev

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends --quiet \
    build-essential \
    libmagickwand-dev \
    && apt-get clean all

RUN pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg

RUN apt-get install -y librabbitmq-dev libssl-dev
RUN pecl install amqp
RUN docker-php-ext-enable amqp

RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

RUN docker-php-ext-install sockets

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN docker-php-ext-install zip exif pcntl pdo mysqli pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm"]

And Nginx app.conf
server
{
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html;
    location ~ \.php$
    {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location /
    {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}

Nginx docker logs
webserver  | 172.18.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2024:14:29:11 +0000] "GET / 
HTTP/1.1" 500 731 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 
Safari/537.36"
webserver  | 172.18.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2024:14:29:12 +0000] "GET 
/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 731 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 
(X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
webserver  | 172.18.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2024:14:29:27 +0000] "GET / 
HTTP/1.1" 500 731 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 
Safari/537.36"
webserver  | 172.18.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2024:14:29:27 +0000] "GET / 
HTTP/1.1" 500 731 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 
Safari/537.36"
webserver  | 172.18.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2024:14:29:27 +0000] "GET 
/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 731 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 
(X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
webserver  | 172.18.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2024:15:18:25 +0000] "GET / 
HTTP/1.1" 500 731 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; 
rv:133.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/133.0"
webserver  | 172.18.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2024:15:18:38 +0000] "GET / 
HTTP/1.1" 500 731 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 
Safari/537.36"
 webserver  | 172.18.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2024:15:18:38 +0000] "GET 
/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 731 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 
(X11; 
Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

Php-fpm container logs
172.18.0.3 -  19/Dec/2024:15:18:38 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
172.18.0.3 -  19/Dec/2024:15:18:38 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
172.18.0.3 -  19/Dec/2024:15:23:22 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500


It would be helpful if you could provide the error messages themselves. 500 is a generic Server Error and doesn't provide enough information. You can set DEBUG=true in your .env which will allow the actual error messages to show up. If you could add those error messages to your question, that would be great!

This parameter is already set to true, but unfortunately it doesn’t say anything other than 500 and 502. Docker and Octobercms logs are empty

Hmm, maybe check the nginx logs inside of Docker?

I have attached logs from the nginx container to the question.

Do you have logs for php, php-fpm, and Laravel as well?

I added php logs, there is just a 500 error, laravel logs are clean

Those logs appear to be the access logs. Do you know if the error logs (/var/log/nginx/error.log) have anything in them? Also, is your 500 error a Laravel 500 error (is floating in the center of the page), or an nginx 500 error (is at the top-center of the page with a line underneath and says nginx)?
